# Do lightning spell damage bombs?

Tags: clash-of-clans

If I put a bomb next to a Air Defense and it gets hit by a Lightning Spell, will the spell trigger the bomb to explode or are bombs immune to spells when hidden?

I guess nothing should happen, but I found no evidence or source to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traps are triggered by troops **only**.

And only traps that have HP can be damaged by spells that deal damage, after they have been revealed (as of this writing includes only Hidden Teslas).